# WebStorm Mocha run configuration throws error, command line does not

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webstorm

I am trying to use Mocha (and Chai) to test my Node.js TypeScript code.

When I use WebStorm's Mocha Run Configuration it runs the following command and throws an error

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --require ts-node/register --ui bdd --reporter "/Users/george.pai/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/WebStorm/ch-0/173.3727.108/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js" /Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/src/test/slack.handler.spec.ts --grep "slack\.handler "
```

***However if I run the exact same command from the command line it works fine.***

Here is my run configuration (some directory names obfuscated for privacy)
[image: Mocha Run Config]

My package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-lambda": "0.1.2",
    "json2csv": "^3.11.5",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.5",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "0.0.19",
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.44",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
    "@types/request": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/request-promise-native": "^1.0.10",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.12",
    "serverless-offline": "^3.16.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "tslint-config-standard": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "types": [
    "aws-sdk",
    "chai",
    "mocha",
    "node",
    "request",
    "request-promise-native",
    "typePatches",
    "uuid"
  ]
}
```

Here is the full output of the error

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --require ts-node/register --ui bdd --reporter "/Users/george.pai/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/WebStorm/ch-0/173.3727.108/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js" /Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/src/test/slack.handler.spec.ts --grep "slack\.handler "

/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:307
        throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
              ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
fd-lambdas/src/main/node/slack/slack.handler.ts (57,18): 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (2693)
fd-lambdas/src/main/node/slack/slack.handler.ts (69,12): 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (2693)
fd-lambdas/src/main/node/slack/slack.handler.ts (199,14): 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (2693)
fd-lambdas/src/main/node/slack/slack.handler.ts (202,14): 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (2693)
fd-lambdas/src/main/node/slack/slack.handler.ts (230,16): 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (2693)
    at getOutput (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:307:15)
    at /Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:336:16
    at Object.compile (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:498:11)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:392:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:395:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/src/test/slack.handler.spec.ts:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:392:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:395:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:514:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:484:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: error comes from tsnode. Not sure why it doesn't use your tsconfig.json, but it doesn't look like the IDE problem

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the obfuscation probably hindered finding the solution. The working directory for the Mocha Run Configuration `/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd` was the root of the project, but not the root of my node project `/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas`

Changing the working directory to the proper directory solved this. My terminal was already in the proper directory `/Users/george.pai/Workspace/fd/fd-lambdas` so that is why it worked.